# Systemctl service not killed after timeout on RuntimeMaxSec

Tags: systemctl, systemd-timer

My script runs every minute (with systemctl timer) but it will occasionally hang for ever, meaning that unless I manually stop it, it won't run again. So I implemented a timeout with `RuntimeMaxSec` but it didn't work. (Note: I expect the script to run 1000 times ok, and maybe hang once - I'm fine with that as long as it is killed and next runs are ok)

I'm not sure what kind of signal the service received, or if it even received one. In either case, has anyone run into that issue, and what was your solution? Thanks

service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Run myscript

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/myscript.sh

RuntimeMaxSec=30


[Install]
WantedBy=myscript.timer
```

timer:

```
[Unit]
Description=call myscript periodically

[Timer]
OnCalendar=*-*-* *:*:30
Unit=myscript.service
```

Answer (score 1):

I actually had

```
RuntimeMaxSec=30 # will timeout after 30 seconds
```

Removing the comment worked